# logstash Split path and take certain value by its position [2] and insert it into field

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-grok

I need to extract from a path certain value by its position...

example:
let's say I split this following path into array using '\' as split char
E:\OUM82\APP\Logs\UploadManager_20062019.log
I should get something like this:

```
[0]=E:
[1]=OUM82
[2]=APP (this value I want to take into a field  )
[3]=logs
[4]=UploadManager_20062019.log
```

so,
I'm always want to take whatever in [2]
how do I implement it?
its something with ruby?

**Edit:**

I Tried this approach: (like @baudsp suggested)
but I'm still getting  "_grokparsefailure"

```
grok {
              match => { path => "%{GREEDYDATA:pathDriveSign}\\%{GREEDYDATA:RootFolder}\\%{GREEDYDATA:customerFolder}" }
           }
```

here is the std output:

```
{
      "tags" => [
    [0] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
    [1] "_grokparsefailure"
],
     "agent" => {
            "type" => "filebeat",
    "ephemeral_id" => "bd6ace26-79cd-4297-bfb5-5add9f4b4217",
              "id" => "83fb6261-5872-4d95-853a-44f2cc41d436",
         "version" => "7.0.0",
        "hostname" => "OctUpload"
},
   "message" => "2019-06-13 17:40:34,591 INFO QueriesParserEngine.Run - GSP queries parser engine end. Total run time duration: 00:02:32.1831164 ",
"@timestamp" => 2019-06-22T16:25:26.204Z,
     "cloud" => {
    "provider" => "az",
     "machine" => {
        "type" => "Standard_DS13_v2"
    },
      "region" => "westeurope",
    "instance" => {
        "name" => "OctUpload",
          "id" => "768097b1-bfb9-4939-b99c-5337aede39ca"
    }
},
 "extractor" => "SQLSERVER",
     "input" => {
    "type" => "log"
},
       "ecs" => {
    "version" => "1.0.0"
},
  "@version" => "1",
    "fields" => {
    "logtype" => "log4net"
},
      "host" => {
              "os" => {
           "build" => "14393.2608",
         "version" => "10.0",
            "name" => "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter",
        "platform" => "windows",
          "kernel" => "10.0.14393.2608 (rs1_release.181024-1742)",
          "family" => "windows"
    },
              "id" => "d79c20df-4184-41a8-b95d-83669c8e3fbe",
            "name" => "OctUpload",
    "architecture" => "x86_64",
        "hostname" => "OctUpload"
},
       "log" => {
      "file" => {
        "path" => "E:\\OUM82\\Micron\\TI_DS_FILES\\SQLSERVER_LOGS\\QueriesParser-SQLS-BOMSSPROD66-2_13062019_173801 - Copy.log"
    },
    "offset" => 927068
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

**NB**: I'm not sure it's the best filter to use here, but it's the one I've used the most and it should work.

If you are only interested in the `APP` part of your path, you should be able to retrieve it with the [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) filter.

Supposing that your path is in a field called `path`:

```
grok {
   match => {path => "^%{DATA}\\%{DATA}\\%{DATA:value}\\"}
}
```

The filter will put the value `APP` in the `value` field.

For more information on the grok filter:

- [Official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)
- [Grok pattern tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match)
- [Grok patterns list](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)

Comment: There's also the Dissect filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html

Comment: @mihomir I've never used it, unlike grok, so I used what I was familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

another better solution by Badger from ELK team:

[better solution by Badger from ELK team](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/split-path-and-take-certain-value-by-its-position-2-and-insert-it-into-field/186639?u=nitzanm)

> You cannot do it with mutate+split (which is what I would normally
>   suggest) due to this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/9701), which affects regexps, single quoted
>   string, and double quoted strings.
>
> It is possible using grok if you enable config.support_escapes on
>   logstash.yml... Believe it or not
>
> ```
> grok { 
>    match => { "path" =>
>      "^(?<pathDriveSign>\w{1}):\\\\(?<RootFolder>[^\\\\]+)\\\\(?<customerFolder>[^\\\\]+)\\\\."
>    } 
> }
> ```
>
> will get you
>
> ```
> "RootFolder" => "OUM82",  
> "pathDriveSign" => "E", 
> "customerFolder" => "APP",
> ```
>
> Do not ask me to explain why 4 backslashes are required to represent a
>   single backslash.
>
> ---
>
> There is also a sneaky way to do it in ruby. You cannot have a
>   backslash at the end of a string, so we have a string that contains a
>   backslash and extract the backslash from it.
>
> ```
> ruby {
>     code => '
>         backslash = "\\Z"[0]
>         event.set("components", event.get("path").split(backslash))
>     '
> }
> ```
>
> results in
>
> ```
> "components" => [
>  [0] "E:",
>  [1] "OUM82",
>  [2] "APP",
>  [3] "Logs",
>  [4] "UploadManager_20062019.log" 
> ]
> ```